# OCaml Redefining Infix Operator

Tags: functional-programming, ocaml, infix-notation

An exercise questions asks for an explanation as to why this won't work. Obviously from running the code I see that it doesn't, but I don't see in this case why. The error doesn't clarify much!

```
# let (+) x y z = x + y + z in 5 + 6 7;;
Error: This expression has type int
   This is not a function; it cannot be applied.
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Lets go step-by-step. Fire a REPL and type:

```
# let (+) x y z = x + y + z;;
val ( + ) : int -> int -> int -> int = <fun>
```

We can interpret this `int -> int -> int -> int` as *an infix `+` operator that takes two `int`s and returns an `int -> int` function*.

Lets check that:

```
# let f = 5+6;;
val f : int -> int = <fun>
# f 7;;
- : int = 18
```

That's every step of your intended program working.
The issue with your code is that this doesn't work:

```
# 5+6 7;;
Error: This expression has type int
   This is not a function; it cannot be applied.
```

That happens because function application has a precedence over `+` operator. (In fact, function application has the strongest precedence in OCaml.) So adding the brackets, fixes it (you'll need to restart the toplevel):

```
# let (+) x y z = x + y + z in (5+6) 7;;
- : int = 18
```

Comment: So int -> int -> int -> int can be read as input: int -> int and output: int -> int, or (int -> int) -> (int -> int) ? That is, it's input is a function with type int?

Comment: No `int -> int -> int -> int` means  `int -> (int -> (int -> int))` and only that. While `(int -> int) -> (int -> int)` means a function that takes in an `int->int` function and returns an `int->int` function

Comment: Thank you @Kostya, this targeted a fundamental misunderstanding - that the signature values are right associative.